# Should I be worried about CSP error on inline image insertion?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

When using `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync` with `{ "coercionType": "html" }` in options and with inline image (external URL) - CSP errors are triggered in console.
This error doesn't seem to have any impact on functionality, since picture is still added in preview and is successfully sent to recipient, but I am concerned if it will remain true in the future. Is it safe to ignore this error and continue setting inline images like that?

```
VM15:1 Refused to connect to 'https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/65535_51377258275_023a2ab94b_320_240_nofilter.jpg' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src blob: data: *.res.office.com *.res.office365.com *.fluidpreview.office.net *.cdn.office.net *.services.web.outlook.com *.res.outlook.com login.live.com spoprod-a.akamaihd.net shellprod.msocdn.com *.bing.com *.office.net *.office.com *.office365.com *.officeapps.live.com *.skype.com *.skypeassets.com *.spoppe.com *.onedrive.com my.microsoftpersonalcontent.com substrate.office.de *.office365-net.de *.office.de browser.pipe.aria.microsoft.com *.gateway.messenger.live.com dev.virtualearth.net *.trouter.skype.com *.trouter.io wss://*.trouter.skype.com wss://*.trouter.skype.com:443 wss://*.trouter.io:443 media.licdn.com *.facebook.com onerm.olsvc.com *.qas.binginternal.com *.qas.bing.net wss://*.qas.bing.net:443 wss://*.platform.bing.com wss://*.botframework.com:443 wss://augloop.office.com wss://*.augloop.office.com outlook.live.com graph.microsoft.com *.graph.microsoft.com graph.microsoft.de *.googleapis.com *.office.microsoft.com api.box.com api.dropboxapi.com *.users.storage.live.com www.onenote.com *.storage.msn.com asgsmsproxyapi.azurewebsites.net wss://*.pushd.svc.ms wss://*.pushs.svc.ms wss://*.pushb.svc.ms wss://*.pushp.svc.ms wss://*.svc.ms nleditor.osi.officeppe.net api.tenor.com pptservicescast.officeapps.live.com *.sharepoint-df.com *.sharepoint.com *.sharepoint.de wss://*.delve.office.com:443 wss://*.loki.delve.office.com:443 wss://*.loki.delve.office.com *.delve.office.com *.loki.delve.office.com web.vortex.data.microsoft.com *.events.data.microsoft.com *.online.lync.com *.infra.lync.com *.safelinks.protection.outlook.com wss://*.cortana.ai *.cortana.ai 'self' attachment.outlook.live.net *.adnxs.com api.taboola.com tlx.3lift.com jill.fc.yahoo.com stage-jill.fc.yahoo.com api.msn.com ris.api.iris.microsoft.com arc.msn.com wss://augloop-dogfood.officeppe.com wss://*.augloop-dogfood.officeppe.com wss://augloop-gcc.office.com wss://*.augloop-gcc.office.com".
'https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/65535_51377258275_023a2ab94b_320_240_nofilter.jpg' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.
```

Environment info: Windows, using outlook in browser(Google Chrome).
Outlook 365 doesn't seem to throw this such errors. Don't know about one-time purchase versions

Comment: Can you please share your sample code to try out this use-case?

Comment: We are able to reproduce this issue. We will get back to you soon on this.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue regarding CSP errors in setAsync. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point

Comment: So my question still stands: Will this error affect our users, besides throwing errors in console?
Also, should I create Issue in github for you, for visibility to community?

Comment: Hi Artur, there is no need to create an issue in github - we already have an item in our backlog. We will update more about this issue on this thread.